# Random Forest and substituting different variables

Tags: random-forest

I am working on a model which predicts a binomial variable.  I have millions of records and hundreds of variables to sample from.  I have millions of records from individuals from each of the past several years.  Most of the variables have specific data to the individual and to the year.  However I do have a few variables that vary only on year and not with the individuals.  Meaning that if I have ten years worth of data, I have only 10 unique variables within those millions of records.  Furthermore, I have multiple year only variables that I would like to test to find out which ones will give the best predictive results.  Because there are so few different values within these variables, and they are extremely highly correlated, they give dramatically different predictive results when substituted in and out.

Will the Random Forest analysis allow me to substitute in and out these sets of year variables in order to come up with an average of models based on these different variables?

If this is acceptable, can I, for instances say in R, specify which variable to not substitute, and which variables to substitute only keeping one of them at a time?